# Finding orders where products of both types are present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, subquery

Consider below table tbl:

```
ordernr productId productType
1       12        A
2       15        B
2       13        C
2       12        A
3       15        B
3       12        A
3       11        D
```

How can I get only rows where products of both productType's B and C are present in the order?
The desired output should be below because products of both type B and C are present in the order:

```
2       15        B
2       13        C
2       12        A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be more efficient to use use `exists` twice:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.ordernr = t.ordernr and t1.productid = 'B')
    and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.ordernr = t.ordernr and t1.productid = 'C')
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(ordernr, productid)`.

Answer (score 1):

One method is using a CTE to get the counts and then filter using those in the outer query:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ordernr,
           productId,
           productType
           COUNT(CASE productType WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END) AS BCount,
           COUNT(CASE productType WHEN 'C' THEN 1 END) AS CCount
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ordernr,
       productId,
       productType
FROM CTE
WHERE BCount > 0
  AND CCount > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the `ordernr`s that you need with this query:

```
select ordernr
from tablename
where productType in ('B', 'C')
group by ordernr
having count(distinct productType) = 2
```

So you can use it with the operator `in`:

```
select * from tablename
where ordernr in (
  select ordernr
  from tablename
  where productType in ('B', 'C')
  group by ordernr
  having count(distinct productType) = 2
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0693a582db4d90381ee220a6a1cd1e57).
Results:

```
> ordernr | productId | productType
> ------: | --------: | :----------
>       2 |        15 | B          
>       2 |        13 | C          
>       2 |        12 | A
```